# Can't run executable(s) located in /run

Tags: command-line, permissions, executable

I had created a program which runs completely fine in `/home/me/go/src/health-monitoring-api` and `/home/me/health-monitoring-api` directories.

But when I copied it to `/run` i.e. when the executable is in `/run/health-monitoring-api`
directory, it doesn't run. I ran `sudo ./main.bin`(the executable needs to run with sudo always). It didn't work.

The response was :-
`sudo: unable to execute ./main.bin: Permission denied`

Note: I made it executable with `sudo chmod u+x ./main.bin`

EDIT: Output of `namei -lx /run/health-monitoring-api/main.bin` is...

```
f: /run/health-monitoring-api/main.bin
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
Drwxr-xr-x root root run
drwxr-xr-x root root health-monitoring-api
-rwxr-xr-x root root main.bin
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx /run/health-monitoring-api/main.bin` to the post, please.

Comment: @muru Thanks for looking into the issue. Added that...